# atomic structure ,

Tags: physical-chemistry

one twelveth mass of C-12 isotope is taken to be 1 amu
earlier scientists took the mass of protium isotope of hydrogen as a reference to measure the mass of other atom 
And it is also given that when they did so with hydrogen as reference they got fractional atomic mass for many atoms
but what is the difference between the earlier one and C-12 
both are same and = 1 amu only so why did they get fraction with hydrogen and integer with carbon

pleae explain

Comment: "Was", not "is".

Comment: The title and the body are two distinct entities, and each one is supposed to be meaningful in the absence of the other.

Comment: “one twelveth mass of C-12 isotope is taken to be 1 amu” – No. The old atomic mass unit (amu) referred to the relative atomic mass of oxygen, which was taken as 16. In chemistry, this unit became obsolete in 1961. It was replaced by the unified atomic mass unit (unit symbol: u), which is equal to 1/12 times the mass of a free carbon-12 atom.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/77295/7951

Answer (score 3):

All these choices are arbitrary. Nobody can do justice by summarizing 200 years of atomic weights (now atomic masses) history. Atomic reference scales have changed, earlier hydrogen was taken as 1 (exact) and sometimes oxygen was taken as 16 (exact). Other numbers have been chosen as well. When a mass spectrometer was invented, it started to change the story. It allowed physicists to measure "masses" from pure electricity and magnetism principles without relying on chemical reactions. They started their own scale. So chemists had one set of atomic masses, and physicists had another set of atomic masses. All of them were close but slightly different. This issue affected trade, international business and of course chemical industries. In order to overcome this issue, C-12 was suggested as compromise between chemist's and physicist's scale.

Must read for interested readers: [The carbon-12 scale of atomic masses by
Abbas Labbauf](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1021/ed039p282#)

> earlier scientists took the mass of protium isotope of hydrogen as a reference to measure the mass of other atom And it is also given that when they did so with hydrogen as reference they got fractional atomic mass for many atoms but what is the difference between the earlier one and C-12 both are same and = 1 amu only so why did they get fraction with hydrogen and integer with carbon

Prout's (incorrect) hypothesis was that every element's atomic mass must be an integer multiple of hydrogen's atomic mass. Who stated that if we choose C-12 as the reference, then the atomic masses of other elements become integers?