# What are the units of 85000 Molecular Weight of a polymer

Tags: polymers, terminology

I have a PVA bottle, which says that the molecular weight (Mw) of PVA is between 85000 - 124000.

I know that this means that there are repeated chains of the PVA monomer, but what are the units to the molecular weight (of PVA). Is it $\frac{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{mol}}$? I am having trouble grasping this concept. Or does 85000 - 124000 mean the number of monomers in the chain of this PVA?

Comment: Yes, most likely it is g/mol. Or Da, if you prefer.

Comment: Relative molecule mass is often referred to as molecular weight and is dimensionless. http://goldbook.iupac.org/R05271.html

Comment: Related: [Quick and simple explanation of molar mass, molecular mass and atomic mass](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/32103/7951)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all $M_w$ is not the number of monomers in a chain of PVA. The number of monomers in a chain is called the degree of polymerization.
$\overline {M_w}$ is the **weight average molecular weight**. It is a way of determining the molecular mass of a polymer. As polymer molecules have different chain lengths, the average molecular mass will depend on the method of averaging. For example, we can use the **number average molecular weight** which is based on different type of averaging.

As for the unit, it's as you mentioned: g/mol. In biochemistry, they use the dalton (Da) as a mass unit for biopolymers (1 $N_a.$Da= g/mol, where $N_a.$ is the Avogadro number). So, when we say a protein has a molecular weight of 64000 g·mol$^{−1}$, it has  also a mass of 64 kDa.

P.S. To be rigorous, we have to say ** molecular mass** instead of ** molecular weight**. But this was an old way of naming things.

Comment: So is the molecular weight in case of PVA between 85000 - 124000 g/mol?

Comment: @http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/17750/user5139637 Yes, it is.

Comment: $1\ \mathrm{Da} = 1\ \mathrm{u} = 1.660\,538\,921(73) \times 10^{-27}\ \mathrm{kg}$

Comment: @Loong you are right. But when we say a protein with a molecular weight of 64000 g·mol−1, it has  also a mass of 64 kDa.