# What do we have both r.a.m. and r.m.m.?

Tags: units

Read Orthocresol's answer here first: [What is the difference between "molecular mass", "average atomic mass" and "molar mass"?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38082/what-is-the-difference-between-molecular-mass-average-atomic-mass-and-mola)

Orthocresol, in his answer, says that atomic mass is the weighted average mass of the atoms of an element and molecular mass is the mass of the molecule of an element/ compound obtained by adding the atomic masses of the constituent element's/ elements' atoms. Both atomic mass and molecular mass have the units of mass which may be kilograms, grams, daltons or a.m.u.

Relative atomic mass/ atomic weight is the ratio between the atomic mass of an atom and 1/12th of the atomic mass of a C-12 atom and similarly, relative molecular mass/molecular weight is the ratio of the molecular mass of a molecule and 1/12th of the atomic mass of a C-12 atom. Both R.A.M. and R.M.M are unitless since they are the ratio of two physical quantities which have the units of mass.

**My Question**: Atomic masses and molecular masses expressed in a.m.u or u have the same numerical value as R.A.M. and R.M.M respectively. What is the point of having R.A.M and R.M.M?