# How are the molar mass and molecular mass of any compound numerically the same?

Tags: atoms, mole, atomic-structure

This observation is really annoying me, and the internet isn't providing me with any solid answers. Either their definitions of molar mass completely differ, or they don't stick to their own definition while actually calculating the molar mass of a certain element or compound.

Now, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Molar_mass&oldid=852072762),

> The molar mass *M* is a physical property defined as the mass of a given
>   substance (chemical element or chemical compound) divided by the
>   amount of substance.

and it's unit is

> g/mol

My understanding of this is that we're calculating the total mass of all the atoms(or molecules) present in **1 mole** of that element(or compund). This means that we would have to take the **atomic mass** of that element and multiply it by the number of atoms present in 1 mole of that element, which is **6.022 × 10^23** atoms.

So for example, the **relative molecular mass** of water is 18.02 u, and it's almost the same as the **molar mass** of water, which is 18.015 g/mol.

So my question is, how is **18.02 u × (6.022 × 10^23) = 18.015 g/mol**?

Comment: Approximations? Conceptually, they should be identical - considering the same material, i.e. either the relative molecular mass and the relative molar  mass, or both isotopic.

Comment: Related: [Quick and simple explanation of molar mass, molecular mass and atomic mass](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32089/7951)

Answer (score 5):

> So for example, the **relative molecular mass** of water is 18.02 u, and it's almost the same as the **molar mass** of water, which is 18.015 g/mol.
>
> So my question is, how is **18.02 u × (6.022 × 10^23) = 18.015 g/mol**?

That is not quite correct.

The **relative molecular mass** $M_\mathrm r$ of water is a dimensionless quantity, i.e. the unit for relative molecular mass is the unit one and not $\mathrm u$:

$$M_\mathrm r=18.015\,28$$

It's the **average mass per molecule** $m_\mathrm f$ that has the unit $\mathrm u$:

$$m_\mathrm f=18.015\,28\ \mathrm u$$

Note that

$$1\ \mathrm{u}=1.660\,538\,921(73)\times10^{-27}\ \mathrm{kg}$$

Also note that you are missing the unit of the Avogadro constant:

$$N_\mathrm A=6.022\,140\,857(74)\times10^{23}\ \mathrm{mol^{-1}}$$

Thus

$$\begin{align}
M&=m_\mathrm f\cdot N_\mathrm A\\[6pt]
&=18.015\,28\ \mathrm u\times N_\mathrm A\\[6pt]
&=18.015\,28\times1.660\,538\,921\times10^{-27}\ \mathrm{kg}\times N_\mathrm A\\[6pt]
&=18.015\,28\times1.660\,538\,921\times10^{-27}\ \mathrm{kg}\times6.022\,140\,857\times10^{23}\ \mathrm{mol^{-1}}\\[6pt]
&=0.018\,015\,28\ \mathrm{kg\ mol^{-1}}\\[6pt]
&=18.015\,28\ \mathrm{g\ mol^{-1}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Note that this answer was valid until the redefinition of the SI base units came into force on 20 May 2019.